# Nodejs Express - how to set max-old-space-size in package.json?

Tags: node.js, express

I was getting Javascript heap out of memory error.

So I made this change to my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 app.js && node ./bin/www"
  },
```

which used to be

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
  },
```

Now if I run npm start, the server is not up and running. If I try to access any page, I get unable to connect to server error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's in `app.js`?

Comment: the answer is not working?

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for you:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
  },
```

You need to pass the `--max-old-space-size=4096` param like this:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./bin/www",
      },
```

Comment: How to verify if this is really working.? 
When I am checking with "node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))'"     Its not increased